# C++ - No matching constructor

Tags: c++, list, struct, containers

I was wondering if anyone can help me out.  I am trying to either use a list or a struct as a container to count the frequency of letters in a text file and am having some trouble figuring out the solution.

I have some code below and was first trying to use a `struct` but can't figure out how to easily navigate this object with a pointer.  Does anyone have examples of how to add to and walk through entries in a `struct`?  Isn't a `struct` like an expandable container?

If I can use the `std::list` I would rather do that but couldn't really find any examples on this site or on the web that were useful enough after reading the `std::list` documentation. I need a `char` variable and an integer the `char` contains the letter found and the integer is the counter of how many times I found each letter.

Can anyone here help?

Thanks.

Code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct LetterBox {
    char letter;
    size_t frequency;
    LetterBox* Next;
    LetterBox(char ch, size_t count, LetterBox* ptr)
    {
        letter = ch;
        frequency = count;
        Next = ptr;
    }
};

int main() {

    new LetterBox(' ',0,nullptr);
//    new LetterBox(' ',0,nullptr);
    int count = 0;
    char ch;
    string line;
    string FileName;

    cout << "Enter the name of the textfile: ";
    cin >> FileName;

    ifstream file (FileName);
    if (file.is_open())
        while (file.good())
        {
            while(getline(file, line)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(line); i++) {
                    ch = toupper(line[i]);
                    count++;
                    cout << ch;

                }
            }
            file.close();
        }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file:" << FileName << endl;
        return 1;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use maps: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/. You should, in general, never use `struct`s in C++.

Comment: Why not to use std::map<char,size_t> to directly associate chars and its counters?

Comment: Your 'LetterBox' struc can have an Array or List as contain class. Or you can use linked-list.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going to look into using the std::map as a solution.

Comment: @DYZ `struct` is just `class` with default public access rather than default private access. You wouldn't say never use `class` in C++ so why would you say to never use `struct`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I said "in general." There may be exceptions. However, default public access defies the concept of encapsulation, which is quintessential for any good OOL.

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment a bit, using std::map like you use dict in some other languages, it is Quicker, easier, more seductive and already solve problems if you want to support UTF encoding later.

But if you already know it will only be used for ASCII text there is another way.

Your universe for ASCII is 0-255 (actual 0-128 but lets ignore that in case someone use the extended ASCII). This mean that we can actually in reasonable space cover all outcomes with a

```
std::array<std::size_t, 256> letters= {0};
```

You can then replace your inner loop with

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(line); i++) {
  ch = toupper(line[i]);
  letter[ch]++;
}
```

And later write out the result

```
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
  std::cout << "Letter: '" << ch << "' occured " << letter[ch] << " times\n";
}
```

This should be roughly the same space usage as a `std::map` but better locality and far better lookup time. You could get by with using only 27 letters but that adds more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested in comments under your question, the [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is what do you need. With `std::map` you can map the number of occurrences to the corresponding characters.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::string hello { "Hello, World!" };
    std::map<char, std::size_t> letterCounts;

    for(char ch : hello)
        letterCounts[ch]++;

    for(auto& elem : letterCounts)
        std::cout << elem.first << ": " << elem.second << std::endl;
}
```

The [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is good when you intend to use a container with fast insertion and removal abilities. Accessing elements inside an `std::list` is slow.

Comment: `std::vector` will beat `std::list` in practice though. Modern CPUs *really hate* chasing pointers and perform much better on something prefetcher friendly. Try it; regardless of `std::list` being theoretically (big O) better than `std::vector` for insertions, I will bet real money that you'll see `std::vector` out-perform it almost every single time. In my experience, `std::list` is close to the *worst* data structure you can pick for modern CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for which I have used `map` and `structured binding` for counting the frequency of the letter

New Feature of c++17 used

> 1.If statement with initializer
>
> 2. Structure Binding

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<char,int> counterOfChar;
    std::string My("Once upon a time there was a lion who was very funny in reading text and counting them");
    std::for_each(My.begin(), My.end(), [&counterOfChar](const char& n)
    {   //'if' initialization statements are a C++1z extension
        
        if (auto [iter,success] = counterOfChar.insert(std::make_pair(toupper(n),1) ) ;success == false)
        {
            counterOfChar[iter->first] = ++iter->second;
        }
    });
    for (const auto &[character,count]:counterOfChar)
    {
        std::cout<<character<<" "<<count<<std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output

```
  17
A 6
C 2
D 2
E 8
F 1
G 2
H 3
I 5
L 1
M 2
N 10
O 5
P 1
R 3
S 2
T 6
U 3
V 1
W 3
X 1
Y 2
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: I think I'm pretty close but for some reason my program is counting more 'C' 's for some reason but all the other characters seem to count fine.

Comment: @Cory Hall Great if you want you can post your new code